# Gzip Decompression not working as configured input in stream analytics job

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am sending compressed Gzip stream to IoT hub and forwarding it to Azure stream analytics as input. I have configured ASA input endpoint with compression type Gzip and serialization type JSON, but it fails with error Invalid compression and serialization type.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack overflow..!

**Note:** Make sure input compression type should match with the data selected from Azure IoT Hub.

Data errors are errors that occur while processing the data. These errors most often occur during data de-serialization, serialization, and write operations. When data errors occur, Stream Analytics writes detailed information and example events to the diagnostic logs. In some cases, summary of this information is also provided through portal notifications.

**InputDeserializerError.InvalidCompressionType**

- Cause: The input compression type selected doesn't match the data.
- Portal notification provided: Yes
- Diagnostic log level: Warning
- Impact: Messages with any deserialization errors including invalid compression type are dropped from the input.
- Log details
  Input message identifier. For IoT Hub, the identifier is the PartitionId, Offset, and Sequence Number.

For more details, refer "[Azure Stream Analytics Data Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/data-errors)".

Hope this helps.